# How do I add a repository from behind a proxy?

Tags: command-line, proxy, gnupg, add-apt-repository

I've a problem at the office. We're behind a proxy (which is set and applied at ubuntu proxy settings) and when I try to add a repository from terminal, I get:

> Error reading --some url here--: urlopen error [Errno 113] No route to host

**I've tried with**

- Launchpad-getkeys script. I get this (image)

[image]

- I've tried with another "hack", without luck

  1. Press Alt-F2 and type `gksu gedit /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py`
  2. Find line 88, change `keyserver.ubuntu.com` to `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`
  3. Save, close and reboot.

**Does anyone know if I could solve this problem in any way? Thanks**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue is described on this following [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/516032), It seems that the proper fix is described at [commment #11](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/516032/comments/11):

1. Set the variable `https_proxy` to your proxy
2. Edit `/etc/sudoers` or the correct file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` so it contains:

   ```
   Defaults env_keep = https_proxy
   ```

Comment: Joao, I've added variables to /home/myuser/.bashrc, then added the env_keep stuff to /etc/sudoers, and now when I execute this command "sudo env | grep proxy" I get the variables showing. When I add a repository or execute the launchpad-getkeys script, I don't get errors anymore. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

The script you've mentioned - [launchpad-getkeys](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/launchpad-getkeys-gets-proxy-support.html) now has proxy support.

Comment: Although I solved the question with the /etc/sudoers, I also read the launchpad-getkeys news in the rss feed, and now with -p http://ip:port this is an awesome feature! thanks Alin !!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-HE` option of `sudo`:

```
sudo -HE apt-key [...]
```

It will keep your proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the root account and add the repository from there:

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:xxxyyy/ppa
```