# Adding a ppa repo and get key signed - no valid OpenPGP data - proxy issue?

Tags: ppa, proxy, gnupg

I want to get a ppa key signed

I tried

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A258828C     

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A258828C
gpg: requesting key A258828C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

and

```
wget -q http://ppa.launchpad.net/panda3d/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg -O- | apt-key add -

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I am behind a proxy , in apt.conf it is configured correctly

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.mycompany.de:3128";
```

I also tried setting proxy

```
export http_proxy="proxy.mycompany.de:3128"
export https_proxy="proxy.mycompany.de:3128"
```

Comment: i think this solution can resolve your problem -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/23211/problem-adding-repositories-and-connecting-from-terminal-behind-a-proxy another work around is `gpg –keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 –recv-keys A258828C`

Comment: sorry it's `sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys A258828C`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.de:3128; export https_proxy=$http_proxy
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A258828C
```

Comment: it works, thanks so much! ( `sudo -E` is the key for me )

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to use sudo?

If you did and it failed, also try this:

```
sudo gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv A258828C
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running `sudo -s` before

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A258828C
```

This worked for me.