# Cannot add repository due to "couldn't connect to host" error

Tags: ppa, repository, add-apt-repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get add-apt-repository to work through a proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy)

I am unable to add repositories in my ubuntu 12.04. 
I am getting an error whenever I try to add repository.following is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

Please help me out with this,