# Unable to add PPA, Help needed?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't add PPA repositories!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131982/i-cant-add-ppa-repositories)

When I typed this command in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
```

I got the following error. Please help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

Answer (score 0):

The output says "couldn't connect to host".  Try making sure that you are connected to the internet and can reach the ppa server.  You can also add the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main`

Comment: For example: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/java/ubuntu precise main

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following:

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

This will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can still add PPA through Synaptic Package Manager.

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager.

   [image: Step-1]
2. Go to Settings > Repositories > Other Software > Add

   [image: Step-2]
3. Now add the PPA

   [image: Step 3]
4. Reload to apply changes.