# Can't add any ppa in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ppa, netflix, lightread

I've made a clean install of 13.04 and just can't add any ppa I try. The output is always the same, something about my internet connection (that works fine with anything else). Heres an example (sorry my instalation is in portuguese)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio 
[sudo] password for andre:
Não foi possível obter informações do PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ehoover/+archive/compholio), por favor verifique sua conexão com a internet.
andre@sapienz:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/lightread
Não foi possível obter informações do PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~cooperjona/+archive/lightread), por favor verifique sua conexão com a internet.
```

A possible translation would be "It was not possible to obtain information from the PPA, please verify you internet connection."

I'm NOT behind a PROXY, so this is not [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131982/i-cant-add-ppa-repositories).
I don't know what could be doing this, and I really need to install some apps like netflix and lightread to make this installation worthy. Thank you

Comment: Have you verified that your internet is working?

Comment: Have you even tried the solution in the other question?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue that i cannot add PPA just 2,3 days back. My internet was working the only things that was not working was adding PPA. So when i add ppa in Y ppa manager **Boom** it was added and working.

> **Y PPA Manager**, like the name says, is a tool to manage PPAs: add, remove, purge PPAs, search for packages in Launchpad PPAs, list packages in a PPA and lots more, all from a single user interface.

[Complete Feature List](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager)

**Install Y PPA Manager**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

> Open Y ppa From Dash

[image]

> Enter Your Admin Password

[image]

> Double Click On Add PPA

[image]

> Enter The PPA Click Ok To Confirm

[image]

Then `sudo apt-get update` after that install package `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have the same problem trying to install Y PPA manager. It tries to connect to `https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager` like netflix and lightread. If i recall it should try to connect to `https://launchpad.net/webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager` or something like that instead of this /api/1.0 thing.

Comment: @AndreLacerda Go to System Settings > Software Source > Select Download From Tab > Select Other > Select Best Server

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired adding the PPA via Software Center?

```
Open Ubuntu Software Center, then go to the top menu bar, and select 'edit' and then select 'Software Sources'.
```

Try adding it that way and see if it goes.

Do you have any type of firewall settings configured incorrectly or something that could be blocking the ppa? I would also check out to make sure the ppa was typed correctly.

Hopefully that helps. :)