# How to install Google Dart in Ubuntu?

Tags: googledart

How can I install Google Dart in my Ubuntu? Is it pre-installed with 
Ubuntu or have to install manually ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install google dart in Ubuntu , open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hachre/dart
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install darteditor dartsdk dartium
```

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: s-dayal-shri  http://askubuntu.com/questions/131982/i-cant-add-ppa-repositories

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hachre/dart/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 2):

You can also follow [official installation guide for Linux](https://dart.dev/get-dart#install-using-apt-get) from Dart docs:

Setting up Dart repository

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
```

Installing Dart SDK using `apt-get`:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install dart
```

Exporting SDK path (you can append following line at the end of your `.bashrc` file):

```bsh
 export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Dart is available as part of [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install umake
```

After that just run the Dart installer as your user (don't use sudo in this case):

```
umake dart
```

It will prompt you where to install Dart, and then download it automatically and install it.

Comment: Cannot find `umake` for me when trying to install