# Adding an apt repository when using a web proxy

Tags: installation, apt, proxy, add-apt-repository

I have been trying to install Wine on Ubuntu 12.04 and I don't seem to be winning.

I keep getting this error:

```
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (56, 'Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT')
```

Please, can someone assist?

Comment: You shouldn't use a ppa for wine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software? also games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-also-games)

Comment: Close voters: how is this a duplicate of that question? It doesn't solve his problem at all. It's a proxy issue, and someone posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you connect to the Internet through a proxy? In this case, check your login and password for proxy in System settings or try execute commands in terminal:

```
   sudo -i
   export http_proxy="http://login:pass@ip:port"
   add-apt-repository <PPA URL>
```

For more information read [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy).

If you want to disable proxy for "apt-get" read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/168927/194229)

P.S. You don't need PPA for Wine. There is a stable version in the official repository.