# Can't connect to ubuntu keyserver when guest in virtualbox

Tags: apt, virtualbox, 10.04, gnupg

I'm trying to install an application on an Ubuntu 10.04 via a ppa. This setup is necessary since a customer's error seems to be platform dependent.

Here's what

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/app
```

I get:

```
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmphf6_87/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmphf6_87/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
recv failed
```

I tried `ping keyserver.ubuntu.com` and it worked. I googled the problem but I found nothing.

Comment: Are you required to use a proxy server, or is a firewall blocking port 11371? Otherwise it might just be a temporary issue. I can confirm keyserver.ubuntu.com is working right now.

Comment: Indeed! When I do `nmap -p 11371 keyserver.ubuntu.com`, it tells me that this port is filtered. It might be filtered by the ubuntu server but that wouldn't really make sense, would it. So, I guess, I have to talk to the admin. If you make that an answer, I can mark this issue as solved.

Comment: You probably don't need to, see my answer.

Comment: In our case in was VPN issue - it was blocking connection to port `11371`

Answer (score 1):

It seems your network filters access to port `11371`, which is used by the hkp protocol by default.

To workaround this issue, select another key server that is also available on port 80, by adding the `--keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80` flag to `add-apt-repository`. This selects one of the [key servers available on port 80 from the SKS key server network](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php#pool_p80).

In case port 80 is also only available behind a proxy, you could

- [use `hkps` for retrieving keys, which uses https on port 443](https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php#pool_hkps) and might not be proxied
- [configure the proxy in `apt-add-repository`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy)