# How to update jdk 7?

Tags: apt, java, ppa, jdk

I am using ubuntu 14.04 version, 64 bit. when I give `java -version` in terminal, I get :

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

So I have jdk version 1.7.0_65 already running in my system. How can I update to jdk version 1.7.0_80?

Please give instructions in detail.. step by step..

Note : 
Am not able to use ppa. 
When I give `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`, it gives an error :

```
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Is there any other way to update jdk without using ppa?

`echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/loc‌​al/games:/usr/local/go/bin
```

`apt-cache policy openjdk-7-jdk`

```
openjdk-7-jdk:
  Installed: 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Version table:
     7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7u51-2.4.6-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  golang-doc golang-go golang-go-linux-amd64 golang-src
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-source visualvm icedtea-7-plugin
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei ttf-telugu-fonts
  ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 521 not upgraded.
Need to get 55.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 220 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Could not connect to 192.168.5.100:80 (192.168.5.100), connection timed out
0% [Connecting to 192.168.5.100 (192.168.5.100)]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Could not connect to 192.168.5.100:80 (192.168.5.100), connection timed out
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jre amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Unable to connect to 192.168.5.100:80:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Unable to connect to 192.168.5.100:80:
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jdk_7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 192.168.5.100:80 (192.168.5.100), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre_7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 192.168.5.100:80:

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to 192.168.5.100:80:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
anjana-pt443@anjana-pt443:~$ 
anjana-pt443@anjana-pt443:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

`ifconfig` :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:67:c1:99  
          inet addr:192.168.225.34  Bcast:192.168.225.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6be:d9ff:fe67:c199/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:786519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1007030240 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:27039436 (27.0 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e6700000-e6720000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2510995 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:2510995 (2.5 MB)
```

`cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet 
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: output of echo $PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/go/bin

Comment: You have 521 not upgraded packages? Shame on you! When you ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as suggested by @A.B., did you also get network errors like those the `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` showed? Do you have internet access? Can you browse websites? If no, can you `ping google.com`? If no, can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Am not able to ping google.com and 8.8.8.8; but i can browse websites and i have internet access.

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: `# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts`
 `::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`
 `fe00::0 ip6-localnet`
 `ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix`
 `ff02::1 ip6-allnodes`
`ff02::2 ip6-allrouters`

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the output there. And the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Answer (score 1):

Taken from your updated question:

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main openjdk-7-jdk amd64 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
  Could not connect to 192.168.5.100:80 (192.168.5.100), connection timed out
```

You have a serious problem with your network.

Some possibilities:

- a misconfigured router/DNS server
- a restricting proxy
- a restricting firewall
- you are part of an intranet with restricted internet access

---

The current version for OpenJDK is 1.7.0_79 in the officially [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-7&searchon=names).

Therefore:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

The error message

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

is a temporary problem. Try ist again later.

Comment: it doesnt change anything. after i gave `sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` , and checked the version, its stil the same.

Comment: @Ridhima Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` to explicitly ask the system to update this specific package.

Comment: @ByteCommander : i have edited the question and given there what I got when I gave this cmd. The version stil didnt change.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly at odds with A.B. the latest version of `openjdk-7-jdk` is `7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2`, but your Apt output shows serious network issues:

```
Could not connect to 192.168.5.100:80 (192.168.5.100), connection timed out
```

`192.168.*.*` is a local address so one of two things has happened here:

- You have incorrect [proxy settings for Apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257290/configure-proxy-for-apt). If you are behind a proxy, [`add-apt-repository` needs proxy settings too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy).
- Your DNS is resolving `in.archive.ubuntu.com` (and other domains) to `192.168.5.100`. This seems *much* less likely, but you can test with `ping in.archive.ubuntu.com` and check the IP is correct (not this local IP). This isn't impossible. A bad public wifi access point might redirect traffic around like this to force you into a portal.

The solution is essentially "fix your networking" but that should put you on the right path.

Comment: am not able to ping in.archive.ubuntu.com.

Comment: What IP does it resolve as though?

Comment: it resolves to 91.189.92.201

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)  . I manually did it and the version got changed to jdk1.7.0_80. Thanks for your time @A.B , @Oli and @Byte Commander.