# Configure GPG to use system proxy and port 80 via it's config

Tags: apt, proxy, 16.10, gnupg

I'm trying to improve [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/252082/171636). As you can guess, `add-apt-repository` doesn't work through proxy, and accepted answer doesn't work for me. I tried:

- Setting and preserving local variables

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://proxy:port
  export https_proxy=$http_proxy
  sudo -E
  ```

  which just does nothing
- editing `/etc/environment` has same effect
- editing sudoers' file has same effect besides graphical apps cannot access mir

The mentioned answer helps, but doesn't fix the problem, because `add-apt-repository` cannot be simply modified to use proxy and keyserver port 80 every time. Lurking more I discovered that real problem is gpg configuration, which is badly documented. I just couldn't realize how to set `http-proxy` option or to `honor-system-proxy` permanently.

Trying to set option `honor-http-proxy` I wrote `~/.gnupg/dirmng.conf` with such contents, but it didn't help:

```
honor-http-proxy
```

Also, I had no such problem before, in Ubuntu 8.04 — 16.04. Yep, the problem may be not in the proxy config, but in the keyserver port. If so, I'd like to set keyserver to use port 80 by default.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Even if an HTTP proxy is used, the proxy might not like the port the keyserver uses, so I tend to set a keyserver that uses port 80: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75892/70524

Comment: Yep. If so, I'd like to save this config option too. BTW, I had no such problem in 16.04.