# add-apt-repository wont work on proxy

Tags: 11.10, package-management, apt, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a repository from behind a proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23211/how-do-i-add-a-repository-from-behind-a-proxy)

I would like to send an add-apt-repository command via the gnome-terminal on my Ubuntu 11.10 laptop that is connected through a proxy (with username/password).
Following this answer, I edited my apt.conf file:
[how to install packages with apt-get on a system connected via proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy/89695#89695)

#### /etc/apt/apt.conf

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>/";
```

I can now run `apt-get install package-name` with no problem, but when I try `add-apt-repository`, it won't work. Any suggestions?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 65, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    lp_page = urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1209, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1171, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:503: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as suggested here, as someone has already solved this problem:

[How do I add a repository from behind a proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23211/problem-adding-repositories-and-connecting-from-terminal-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/516032).

According to one of the subscribers you can go around this by using these steps:

> `sudo visudo`
>
> then add the following lines
>
> `Defaults env_keep="http_proxy"`
>   `Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"`
>
> then:
>
> `sudo bash`
>   `export https_proxy=http://[username:password@]www.proxy.com:8000/`
>   `add-apt-repository ppa:<whatever>`