# I can't add PPA repository behind the proxy

Tags: apt, ppa, aptitude, curl

I'm trying to add the ppa repository (as a root) with the following command:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://firstname.surname@xxx.com:my_pass@165.x.x.232:8080"
add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (56, 'Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT')
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Looks like curl is connecting to the proxy, but the proxy says that Authentication is Required.
I've tried with .curlrc, http_proxy env instead, but it doesn't work.

```
strace -e network,write -s1000 add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr("165.x.x.232")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
getsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr("165.x.x.232")}, [16]) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46025), sin_addr=inet_addr("161.20.75.220")}, [16]) = 0
sendto(4, "CONNECT launchpad.net:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: launchpad.net:443\r\nUser-Agent: PycURL/7.22.0\r\nProxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\nAccept: application/json\r\n\r\n", 146, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 146
recvfrom(4, "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required\r\nProxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm=\"proxy\"\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nProxy-Connection: close\r\nSet-Cookie: BCSI-CS-91b9906520151dad=2; Path=/\r\nConnection: close\
```

Maybe it's because there is @ sign in the username? Wget works with proxy fine.

Related:
[How do I add a repository from behind a proxy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23211/how-do-i-add-a-repository-from-behind-a-proxy)

**Environment**

Ubuntu 12.04

curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3

curl Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

**UPDATE**

When added credentials into .curlrc

```
cat ~/.curlrc 
proxy = 165.x.x.232:8080
proxy-user = name.surname@xxx.com:mypass0
```

It seems to work for the **plain curl**.

```
curl www.google.com | head

* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'name.surname@xxx.com'
GET HTTP://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: Basic cmFmYWwud2llY3pvcmVrQHVi...3R0RDA=
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
```

Also HTTPS:

```
curl -v https://www.google.com | head
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.google.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'name.surname@xxx.com'
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic cmFmYWwud2llY3pvcmVrQHVi...3R0RDA=
    > User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1     zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* successfully set certificate verify locations
```

But still doesn't work when adding ppa certificate.

```
pycurl.error: (56, 'Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT')
```

**CURL HEADERS**

Headers sent:

```
CONNECT launchpad.net:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: launchpad.net:443
Proxy-Authorization: Basic cGVvcGxlcmVhbGx5c2hvdWxkQHNhbml0aXplcG9zdHM=
User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

**PyCURL HEADERS**

Headers sent:

```
CONNECT launchpad.net:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: launchpad.net:443
User-Agent: PycURL/7.22.0
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: application/json
```

Reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="proxy"
```

It seems that PyCURL doesn't re-send any Authorization when requested.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but this doesn't help. To make sure that this is not the case, I've included my credentials in .curlrc (without escaping @ seems to work for standard curl command), but not for pycurl. See the updated section.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I missed something. I've reported the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1075180

Comment: Have you also set https_proxy? See bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/516032

Comment: Maybe it is a problem related to sessions and environment vars. You could try to export http_proxy and https_proxy in /etc/profile, then reboot the machine (if possible) and try it again.

Comment: Related to what jap1968 is saying above me, I'd made sure that both http_proxy *and* HTTP_PROXY are set (and https_proxy and HTTPS_PROXY).  Thanks to Linux's case-sensitivity, those are actually two different variables - and, best of all, not all programs will use one or the other.

Granted, it sounds more like an issue with how the username/password combination is being sent (because of '@'), but it's worth a shot anyway.

Comment: Similar: [How to run “sudo apt-get update” through proxy in commandline?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7470/how-to-run-sudo-apt-get-update-through-proxy-in-commandline)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Workaround if `apt-get` still works behind the proxy

- add sources manually to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- add gpg key

### Adding sources manually

I think on launchpad.net every ppa still contains a small description how to add sources manually. The launchpad site for your mentioned ppa `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` is https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8. If you scroll down you see an expandable label **Technical details about this PPA**. If you expand it you find the description how to add sources manually. Add the following lines to mentioned `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu quantal main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu quantal main
```

Of course you have to adjust quantal to whatever version you are currently using.

### Adding the Signing Key

The description also contains a *signing key*. This is important, so that your system can always verify that you actually access a trustworthy ppa-address. In case of your ppa that is `1024R/4C9D234C`(can also be found under **Technical details about this PPA**), where the number behind the slash is important.
You can add the fingerprint via the `apt-key` program. Typically you would perform the following command

```
 sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 4C9D234C
```

#### Adding if `apt-key` doesn't work through proxy

Since you already had problems with the `add-apt-repository` program this might not work either. So instead you can download and add the 1024 Bit key manually. If `wget` works you can do that in one step.

```
wget "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x531EE72F4C9D234C" -O out && sudo apt-key add out && rm out
```

Otherwise safe "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x531EE72F4C9D234C" in e.g. `/path/key` and use `sudo apt-key add /path/key` to add it.

### Close with the usual

Afterwards you have to update the repository information `apt-get update` and then you should be able to download the packages.

## Resources

My personal favorite on how to use the packaging mechanism (sadly in German):
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paketquellen_freischalten/PPA

The launchpad version also mentions all the important points:
https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/InstallingSoftware

Since it is untypical to use apt-key in the described way I only found the information in the man pages, `man apt-key`.

Related answer that pretty much describes the standard way to install ppa's manually:
https://askubuntu.com/a/38029/128349

Comment: @kenorb don't know if you get a notification if I edit my post, so: *ping:* "possible workaround"

Comment: If your problem is that the port 11371 is blocked in your corporate firewall, you can now use the port 80 instead: "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4C9D234C"

Comment: This walk-through covers most things. Also consider copying your GPG format key into `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` as well as or instead of `/usr/share/keyrings`: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 8):

Actually it seems to be much easier than the answer posted previously. You just need "sudo" to know that you are behind a proxy and it will work effortlessly. To do this, you need to export your proxy for `http` and `https` the way you usually do:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

and then add `Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"` to then end of `/etc/sudoers` file. After this you should be able to add the ppa using the command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:the_ppa_you_want_to_add`

or use

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:the_ppa_you_want_to_add
```

if you don't want to modify `/etc/sudoers` file. The `-E` option exports environment variables to the sudo user.

I have given a detailed description about this [here on my blog](http://thelittleican.blogspot.in/2013/09/unable-to-add-ppa-behind-proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure **apt proxy** is set like below

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

add following proxy settings and save the file

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http ://proxy.company.com:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https ://proxy.company.com:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://proxy.company.com:port/";
```

in addition export following in Terminal before you run the command

```
export http_proxy=http ://proxy.company.com:port/
export https_proxy=https ://proxy.company.com:port/
```

This should work.