# Is there a secure way to pass authentication parameters for proxy to applications?

Tags: security, proxy, authentication, bashrc

I am behind a proxy server and need to specify authentication parameters to access the internet. For this, I have exported my username, password, host and port_no in my `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file and in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file, which are human readable.

for Example

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<username>:<password>@172.16.0.2:8080/";
```

This causes my password to be openly visible to anyone who has read access to these files.

Is there a secure way of passing these parameters to the applications that need proxy authentication parameters without having to write in such human readable form?

**Note:** It would be good to know of permanent methods. I know I can do this temporarily by exporting each time I open a new session. But I will have to do this everytime I open a new session, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for writing long answer, but `apt.conf` is very sensitive issue of system. So it it necessary to clear all the aspects.

As far as I know `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` accept your proxy settings only if it is given it in human readable form, at most you can force them to read from a different files. I am going to exploit this. I will keep the proxy credentials to files that are not accessible to anyone but root/sudoer user. But one has to unveil the proxy settings to `apt-get` and/or `software-center` before use them every time.

**Secure way to supply proxy to shell environment**

Cut [all the contents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/212132/i-cant-add-ppa-repository-behind-the-proxy/350783#350783) that you put into your `~/.bashrc` in order to supply proxy settings in shell environment and paste to a file say `~/.mybashproxy`. Change `~/.mybashproxy` ownership to root and strip off the read write permission for group and other, so that only sudoers can access them.

```
sudo chown root:root ~/.mybashproxy
sudo chmod go-rw ~/.mybashproxy
```

Make the following alias in `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.bash_aliases`, I would prefer to use the latter.

```
alias begin_proxy='sudo cat .mybashproxy > .tmp; source .tmp; rm .tmp'
```

**Usage**

You have to enable proxy in your shell environment by `begin_proxy` command from terminal providing your `sudo` password. In this way nobody will know your proxy credentials. But after using `begin_proxy` if you allow someone to access the same terminal, he might be able to see your credentials using `env | grep proxy` command in terminal. To be secure do not allow anyone to use the same terminal where you used `begin_proxy`.

**Secure way to supply proxy to apt-get**

`apt-get` and `software-center` use the file `/etc/apt.conf` to preserve proxy settings . Create a file `/etc/apt/myproxy.txt` and [put content of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy/89695#89695) your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` in it from terminal by opening it as,

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/myproxy.txt
```

next copy the desired content and save the file. Remove read write permission of `/etc/apt/myproxy.txt` for group and other as shown above using `chmod`.

Create a temporary file named say `tmproxy.txt` at `/etc/apt/` and give read-write permission for all to it as follows,

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/tmproxy.txt
sudo chmod go+rw /etc/apt/tmproxy.txt
```

I am going to supply proxy settings to `apt-get` and `software-center` from it when necessary. Add the following line in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to read proxy settings from `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`.

```
#inclued /etc/apt/tmproxy.txt;
```

except the above line `/etc/apt/apt.conf` should contain nothing. Now create the following aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias able_apt='sudo cat /etc/apt/myproxy.txt > /etc/apt/tmproxy.txt'
alias disable_apt='echo "0;" > /etc/apt/tmproxy.txt'
```

**Usage**

Before using `apt-get` and/or `software-center` you have to use the command `able_apt` providing your `sudo` password. Then all your proxy credentials will be stored in `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt` and `apt-get` and/or `software-center` will be able to use it. After closing `software-center` or after using `apt-get` to wipe out proxy credentials from `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`, use command `disable_apt`. In this process also no one could see your proxy credentials unless you leave them in `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt` by forgetting to use `disable_apt`

**Notes and Summary**

1. In the alias `disable_apt` the semicolon (`;`) after zero is important otherwise you will get [errors "Extra junk at end of file"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342179/how-to-solve-extra-junk-at-end-of-file-when-using-apt/342180#342180) A red error icon can also appear on top right panel.
2. If you don't have `~/.bash_aliases`, create one. And `source ~/.bashrc` afer making sure that `~/.bashrc` contains the following lines,

```
   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
    fi
```

3. Immediately after doing the above settings to enable aliases either you have to logout and login once or you can use `source ~/.bash_aliases` in terminal.
4. At the end of the story you have three aliases to use:

   - `begin_proxy` - to start proxy in shell environment. Lasts until terminal is open.
   - `able_apt` - to enable `apt-get` and/or `softwere-center` and to store proxy credentials in `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`
   - `disable_apt` - to disable `apt-get` and/or `softwere-center` and to wipe out proxy credentials from `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: +1 for a clever and hacky way! But as I use proxy all the time in my college, I'll have to do this everytime I reboot my machine, that's alright, I'll run it as a cron job at reboot, but yet the file `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt` reveals password without sudo rights, which is an issue. Also I did not understand the role of `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`, when I can directly write the contents of `etc/apt/myproxy.txt` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. Can you explain this?

Comment: Let me clarify the problem. You can not strip off the read permission for group and others from neither `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or a file it is pointing (here `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt`, and it must be there all the time unlike `.tmp` for bash case). In case if you do otherwise, it will give you error and Software center will not open without `sudo`. But we need to hide the credentials. So I proposed this. Feel free to discuss.

Comment: And plz use alias `disable_apt` to purge info from `/etc/apt/tmproxy.txt` while you are away. This hack needs quite effort from user but at the same time does its job nicely.